# MMQGIS export shapefile to KML not working, error message: 'Unknown geometry type 0'. But Point data being used?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, geometry, kml, mmqgis

I'm trying to convert a shapefile (created from a CSV) to a KML using the MMQGIS Plugin (as I want to show styling by attributes on Google Earth.) However, when clicking 'apply' it says 'Unknown Geometry type 0. Use convert geometry tool to change to point, line or polygon'.

The data I am using is Point data, so confused this is an error for the data?

[image: Error Message]

[image: The Data]

Comment: The shapefile spec supports type 0 geometries (Null shapes), but the KML spec doesn't. Are you sure all your shapes are Point type (type 1) values?

Comment: The expecting KML would need to be in Latitude/Longitude for Google Earth. Try re-projecting to WGS84 from OSGB36 first.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're using a Coordinate Reference System (CRS / projection) of EPSG:27700.  When working with or converting to KML, you should always use the basic, EPSG:4326. That's the only projection supported by   Not sure if that's what's causing this error, but certainly something to check.

Answer (score 0):

Before you will use the KML export by the MMQGIS plugin you should reproject your layer. The quickest way to do it is using the "Reproject layer" option in your processing toolbox.

[image]

As the target CRS please ALWAYS select EPSG:4326 - WGS84

Next, you should see the scratch "Reprojected" layer in your panel, which can be exported by the MMQGIS plugin to KML format.